# Select Layer by Attribute clause fails

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I have a shapefile and I want to loop through every column and extract selected features with the specified criteria (Column has a P or L).

So my code is like

```
output = "All.shp"

fields = arcpy.ListFields(output)

for field in fields:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("all.shp", "lyr")
    name = field.name

    clause = name + " LIKE 'P' OR "+ name + " LIKE 'L'"


    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", clause)

    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr", field.name+".shp")
```

Clause fails with ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression.
Tried different things but not working!

Comment: By what do you mean "Seems to fail"?  Such a query can only return rows where the values are 'L' or 'P' (even for numeric fields).  If you meant "contains an uppercase 'P'" then the correct query would be formatted by  `"{:s} like '%P%'".format(field.name)`

Comment: It fails with  ERROR 000358: Invalid expression. I tried what you have sent me and is not working.

Comment: Shapefile may require the fieldname in double-quotes -- try `"\"{:s}\" like '%P%'".format(field.name)`

Answer (score 0):

1. In a whereclause on a shapefile, you need to place the name of the field between 2 " ".
2. When you use LIKE, you should place wildcard characters to replace a single character (_) or a set of characters (%). Also note that it is case sensitive.
   In short, this looks like this :

   ```
   for field in fields:

       arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("all.shp", field.name, """ ("{0}" LIKE '%P%') OR ("{0}" LIKE '%L%' )""".format(field.name))

       arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(field.name, field.name+".shp")
   ```